# so many dialect setting message in log

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

My application run successfully, but when i look in consol (Eclipse consol) 
**Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect]** line is repeated so many times (17 times)

Comment: I do not understand your question: `strong text` is not contained in the log file. Probably you have overridden the word you wanted to put there when formatting.

Comment: Do you call DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.setDialect?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is in the logger configuration. I had the same problem with `log4j` when I configured logging to the multiple files, but I didn't use `additivity` flag. See for details: http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/